# What does the yellow exclamation point above my head mean?

Tags: kamen-rider-memory-of-heroez

Sometimes when an enemy attacks during combat a yellow exclamation point appears above my head. It only appears for some attacks. What does the yellow exclamation point mean?

[image: yellow exclamation point]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A yellow exclamation point means an enemy is attempting a powerful attack that can be countered if you dodge when the attack is close enough to you.

Dodge by pressing <kbd>R2</kbd> then counterattack with <kbd>◯</kbd> when prompted. Counterattacking will restore all RP and in fights with weaker enemies you will restore 10% HP.

[image: counterattack guide]